# rEFInd installation failed (Linux)

Tags: refind

I am trying to install rEFInd. The easiest way I found was to install via the PPA. However upon installation it would fail on the mounting part, mount: special device /dev/mmcblk01 does not exist, followed by umount: //boot/efi: not mounted. One workaround I thought of was to somehow create an alias for mmcblk0p1 as mmcblk01 so when the script tries to mount mmcblk01 it actually mounts mmcblk0p1 instead. The second error would probably fix after having "mmcblk01" mounted.

So is this possible at all? Or should I just manually install it.. as I doubt refind-install would just do the same..

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention that mmcblk0p1 is probably the device it's supposedly trying to mount because mmcblk0 is the device itself, ending up accessing mmcblk01 instead because "1" was appended to mmcblk0 somewhere in the script.

Comment: What kind of computer are you using, the mmcblk0 device is a card reader like SD card. This is probably not a boot device. I don't know how rEFInd is working, but probably the installer probe for operating on all block devices. You may have to find a way to ignore this device.

Comment: It's a laptop, albeit a tablet put into a laptop chasis, hence it has an eMMC as its internal storage device (where Windows 10 is currently installed, mmcblk0).

Comment: I'm rEFInd's developer. This sounds like a bug in the `refind-install` script. I've sent you an e-mail in reply to your e-mail to me about this issue. If you want to work with me to identify and fix the bug, we can do so via e-mail. In the meantime, if you want a working rEFInd, you should follow the [manual installation instructions](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#linux) in the documentation.